# Swift: UIButton not working though connected and other button is working

Tags: swift, button

I cannot figure out, why my button is not working. There are 2 buttons in separate subviews, one is working, the other isn't.

```swift
    @IBOutlet weak var btnAddParameter: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnSave: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func btnAddParaTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        btnSave.isEnabled = false
        addHorizStack()
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnSaveTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("hello")
    }
```

Both buttons have a connected outlet and a connected action (I assigned the one for the non-working button by ctrl dragging to pre-written function in my view controller). I have also re-connected the button.

All (sub)views and the buttons have user interaction enabled.

In [Apple's developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/68169) I found

> I found a solution, in another discussion, where adding contraints to
> the RatingControl for height=44 and width=240 made the view start
> receiving the events.  Now I can hit breakpoint for the
> ratingButtonTapped.  I do not understand why not having the
> constraints prevented it from getting called.

However, no link and I did not find this source. I do have constraints for the button to horiz/vert align with the sub view being the superview to the button.

Any ideas what else I can look for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share storyboard image ? with connection

Comment: Can you see and touch the button, when your app is running?

Comment: @jawadAli pic added

Comment: @LukeSideWalker Yes, I do see the button and it is also enabled (simple text button witch is grey being not enabled and blue being enabled)

Comment: so its not printing "hello" ?

Comment: No, it is not printing hello. The connections look perfectly fine to me and are consistent with the working button. I ctrl-dragged from the view controller item to the button in the left pane and clicked on the available outlet (btnSave) and I ctrl-dragged from the button to the pre-coded lined of the IBAction. I did this procedure already 2 times.

Comment: you added this button in which view ? main view or some other view ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the view structure. The btnAddParameter in the upper sections works, the highlighted Btn Save doesn't. As said above, all (sub)views have user interaction enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. After adding height and width constraints to the sub view being superior to the button, it worked. It appears as if otherwise the subview collapses with regards to user interaction, however, still shows the embedded button.